# How to display my button as none if it's disabled via javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, button

I am using VScode and it shows you the possible functions/variables. However, when I wrote `(button.style.display = "none") & (button.style.display = "block")` VScode didn't seem to give any possibilities in the parenthesis. This translated to no sign of changing on my live server. Pls help!

```
<form class="next_page" type="submit" id="nextButton">
  <button disabled="disabled" onload="remove()"
    <span class="material-symbols-outlined" font- size="32px">arrow_circle_right</span>

    <script remove_hover>
      if (document.getElementbyId('nextButton').disabeld {
        button.style.display = "none"
      } else {
        button.style.display = "block"
      }
    </script>
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Where is your `button` defined? Because in condition you directly query element `document.getElementById('nextButton')` and don't save it in any variable

Comment: for some reason it didn't add my <button disabled="disabled" onload="remove()">

Comment: I just fixed it

Comment: `if (document.getElementById('nextButton').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')) {` this line of code does not make sense

Comment: Did you write this code and are you sure "load" events get fired on a button element?

Comment: I did write the code but literally nothing i have written for this button in javascript has actually made a difference to the server.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
if (document.getElementById('nextButton').disabled)
button.style.display = "none"
else
 button.style.display = "block"
```

Is this you want?